# Python ThreadPoolExecutor to listen to shutdown triggers

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I'm fairly new to writing multi-threading applications, and I'm just starting to learn it on Python. Here's what I'm trying to do which doesn't seem to work as I want to:

1. Using ThreadPoolExecutor to run producer threads to continuously pull information from various websites and insert the results into a queue (for purpose of illustration i'm using only 1 producer thread and a static URL in my code), and 1 consumer thread to read information from the queue (printing to standard out for illustration purposes)
2. I want the application to exit gracefully upon CTRL+C or an OS kill, i.e. consumer thread to finish reading from the queue until it's empty, before we exit

```
    from pypac import PACSession #Inherit machine's proxy settings
    from queue import Queue
    from requests.models import PreparedRequest
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
    from concurrent.futures._base import wait

    import requests
    import signal
    import time    
    
    class Producer:
        def __init__(self, running):
            self.url = "https://reqres.in/api/users"
            self.session = PACSession()
            self.running = running
    
        def put_into_queue(self, queue):
            page = 1
            request = PreparedRequest()
    
            while self.running:
                request.prepare_url(self.url, {"page" : "1"})
    
                if not queue.full():                
                    response = self.session.get(request.url)     
    
                    if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:                        
                        json_response = response.json()
                        response_length = len(json_response)
                        if response_length > 0 :
                            queue.put(json_response)
                            print("Inserted: " + str(response_length))  
                            #page += 1
    
                            time.sleep(10)
    
    
    class Consumer:
        def __init__(self, running):
            self.running = running
    
        def read_from_queue(self, queue):
            while self.running:
                if not queue.empty():
                    items = queue.get()  
                    print("Read: " + len(items))    
            else:
                while not queue.empty() :
                    items = queue.get()  
                    print("Read: " + len(items))  
    
    
    def producer(queue, running):
        producer = Producer(running) 
        producer.put_into_queue(queue)
    
    def consumer(queue, running):
        consumer = Consumer(running) 
        consumer.read_from_queue(queue)
    
    
    def handler(signum, frame):
        print(f'os.signum={signum}')
        global engine_do
        engine_do = False
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":  
        BUF_SIZE = 400
        THREAD_COUNT = 2
        queue = Queue(BUF_SIZE)
    
        engine_do = True
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, handler)
    
        futures = []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(THREAD_COUNT) as executor:
            try:
                futures.append( executor.submit( producer(queue, engine_do) ) )
                futures.append( executor.submit( consumer(queue, engine_do) ) )
    
            except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
                print("KeyboardInterrupt: " + e)
    
        wait(futures)
    
        for succeded, failed in futures:
            print(succeded, failed)
```

However, I can't seem to get the consumer thread to start threading, and each time I run CTRL+C in my powershell window, the application just keeps going.

```
PS C:\Code\vraw_downloader> python .\ProducerConsumer.py
Inserted: 1
os.signum=2
Inserted: 1
os.signum=2
```

Appreciate if someone can advise me how I should fix my code